# what are the smallest and largest values of $||v - w||$? What are the smallest and largest values of $v \cdot w$?

Tags: linear-algebra

If $||v|| = 5$ and $||w|| = 3$, what are the smallest and largest values
of $||v - w||$? What are the smallest and largest values of $v \cdot w$?

How can I solve these two problems? For $||v - w||$ how can you have different values when it is clear that the magnitude of v and w are given?

Comment: Try to draw some pictures in the plane, Explore how the angle between $v$ and $w$ affects the quantities you ask about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hints:

1. Triangle inequality $\|v+w\| \leq \|v\| + \|w\|$
2. Cauchy-Schwarz inequality $|v \cdot w| \leq \|v\|\|w\|$

Comment: For the dot product does that mean the largest value is 15? How would I use that inequality to find the smallest value?

Comment: The absolute value means the inequality is really $-\|v\|\|w\| \leq v \cdot w \leq \|v\|\|w\|$